# How to call function from object

Tags: javascript, function, object

I try to call function from object Foo but it doesn't work.

```js
function Foo(){
    function bar(){
        alert("Hello!");
    }   
}

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();
```

Comment: As you have declared it `bar()` is a local function that is only available inside of the `Foo()` function.

Comment: Such a basic question should not be asked as you can find so many tutorials on Internet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should set the function as object's property

```
function Foo(){
    this.bar = function (){
        alert("Hello!");
    };
}

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();
```

or use prototype to define it before object creation

```
function Foo(){}

Foo.prototype.bar = function (){
    alert("Hello!");
};

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @user3896501's answer,

```js
function Foo() {
  // You can define all private variables/ functions.
  function bar(callBar1) {
    alert("Hello!");

    if (callBar1)
      bar1();
  }

  // This is a private function and can be called only from inside.
  function bar1() {
    alert("Hello!!!");
  }

  // Return only those variables/ functions which needs to be made public
  return {
    bar: bar
  }
}

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();

// Trying to access private function should throw exception
try {
  a.bar1();
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e)
}

// Accessing private function using parameter
a.bar(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Foo()
{
    // ...
}

Foo.prototype.bar = function ()
{
    alert("I called bar on a Foo object");
};

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function Foo(){
    function bar(){
       alert("Hello!");
      }   
   return {
      bar : bar
   }
}

var a = new Foo();
a.bar();
```